# Theme template and hook_theme

Tags: theming

I have a content type 'leg' and a template node--leg.tpl.php.
I'm using [sky](http://drupal.org/project/sky) theme. I have a custom module as well, let's say for example, `mymodule`.
I put the template file into `sites/all/modules/mymodule/theme`. And I created a `hook_theme` and `hook_preprocess_node`.
But my template is not invoked as expected. I cleared all caches.

```
function mymodule_theme(){
    // The base theme registers node.tpl.php.
    $templates['node'] = array(
        'arguments' => array('elements' => NULL),
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/theme',
        'template' => 'node--leg',
        'preprocess functions' => array(
          'template_preprocess',
          'mymodule_preprocess',
          'mymodule_preprocess_node',
          'mymodule_process',
        ),
    );
    return $templates;
}

function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hooks){
    if($vars['type'] == 'leg'){

    }
}
```

When I put my template file into `sites/all/themes/sky/templates` and changed path in `hook_theme` to that location, it works.

```
function mymodule_theme(){
    // The base theme registers node.tpl.php.
    $templates['node'] = array(
        'arguments' => array('elements' => NULL),
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'sky') . '/templates',
        'template' => 'node--leg',
        'preprocess functions' => array(
          'template_preprocess',
          'mymodule_preprocess',
          'mymodule_preprocess_node',
          'mymodule_process',
        ),
    );
    return $templates;
}
```

I would like to know it is a right way or not.
I should not place my template in the sky theme folder, am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by following :

- [override node.tpl.php in a module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17298/override-node-tpl-php-in-a-module)
- [Adding a module path to Drupal 7 theme registry](http://www.metachunk.com/blog/adding-module-path-drupal-7-theme-registry)

Answer (score 1):

`drupal_get_path('theme', 'mymodule')` should be `drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule')`.

Comment: Sorry, it is typo error.

Comment: Ah, no problem. Thought that it might be a very quick fix for you. Have you tried looking at some of the other contributed modules to see how they handle inclusion of templates? You shouldn't have to include the modules templates in a theme unless you were needing to override the module's default templates.

Comment: I have tried several ways, but I failed. I think we cannot override the templates of the default theme from our custom module. `node--leg.tpl.php` in sky theme is invoked automatically without `hook_theme()`. When I tried `hook_theme_registry_alter()`, my template is called, but no variable is not passed to it.